# How does binary addition work?

Tags: logic, binary-arithmetic

I find **binary** confusing. I have watched minecraft redstone videos on binary adders, real binary adders, diagrams, etc and yet I have not learned much at all. *How does electrons flowing through wires made of gold "add/subtract" to make numbers through some logic gates?!*

Comment: If this is the wrong stackexchange, please do refer me to another one and/or move this question to it! Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how the mathematics of binary arithmetic works, or how it is implemented in digital electronics?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the right stackexchange for this question, but here's a basic answer: Given one-bit inputs A and B, the value A XOR B is the output bit and the value A AND B is the output carry bit. The XOR gates and AND gates are built from a few transistors, but you might picture it more easily if built from relay logic. Then you can build a larger circuit to handle longer values like 32-bit registers just like you do decimal place-value arithmetic, adding the carry bit at each place to the two input bits at the next place.

Comment: I think my answer should do. Let me know if you want me to explain anything else.

Comment: what are minecraft redstone videos? are those adders made in minecraft game? it would be helpful to incl link. recently also just found apparent binary adder construction in little big planet... a lot of this is answered by studying boolean arithmetic/algebra (as basically a prerequisite)

Comment: Well in minecraft you can make computers out of redstone; Yes, inevitably, they are adders/subtractors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### It's like magic, isn't it?

Here's a visual depiction for you, and hopefully it will make it easier for you to understand. This circuit is something called a half-adder; a half-adder is a special kind of adder -- the most base level kind of adder -- that takes two values, A and B which are the addend and auged respectively, and outputs them into the sum. If the addend and augend overflow, then the overflow is placed into a special output called $C_{out}$, which means "carry out."

[image: Half Adder]

Well, to chain these together, we need to take two half adders and put them together in order to construct something called a full-adder. What makes a full-adder special is that it takes another input, $C_{in}$ as well as the addend and augend, and performs an addition on all three of those bits.  Here, the half adder I described above has been put into a "black box" kind of configuration, where the visible details of the circuit are hidden, and the inputs and outputs are provided instead. Notice, just like the half-adder, we have a sum and a $C_{out}$ too.

[image: Full Adder]

Well, to construct bigger adders, such as four bit adders, we need to chain those full-adders together, and this is when the pattern becomes even more obvious:

[image: 4-Bit Adder]

And to construct an 8 bit adder, you put two four bit adders together. To construct a 16 bit adder, you put two eight bit adders together. To construct a ... well, you get the point.

---

### So, what's all the 1 and 0 nonsense that I'm hearing about? (Read: how in the heck did someone come up with all of this).

Easy. We have things called "logic gates" which are represented by a couple of symbols to start with, but the simplest way to explain it is in the form of something called a truth table, but what these "True" and "False" values really represent is 1 for true and 0 for false -- but don't worry about that, yet. The first two columns: p|q are a set of truth values that are then evaluated for the other columns. Where $p\wedge q$  represent $p$ and $q$, $p\vee q$ represent $p$ or $q$, and the last column represents $p$ xor $q$

The last operator, `xor` is a special operator. It is the english equivalent of "I either __ or __" and the implication is that both cannot happen at the same time.

[image: Truth tables]

So when we're connecting these in relation to the individual circuit symbols, you can check those out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols).

Putting these all together, with the special truth tables that I've shown you, you can clearly see that in the case of the half adder, walking through a set of logic values you can determine what these propositions mean in terms of those two binary truth values.

So, what's all this mean in terms of our base? Our system of counting? Well, as you may know, it is possible to convert a number of an arbitrary base (ours is 10) to another arbitrary base (in the case of the circuit, it is base two). There are many ways to do that, one of which is by using wolfram alpha; however, the manual way is fun too, if you want to learn how.

Let's count:

0        0000

1        0001

2        0010

3        0011

4        0100

5        0101

6        0110

7        0111

8        1000

9        1001

10       1010

11       1011

12       1100

13       1101

14       1110

15       1111

16      10000 <-- Rollover

The set of numbers on the right are binary numbers. The numbers on the left are numbers in our base, base 10. If you'll notice, the far right column, ex. 000[0], is the 'ones' column. This represents one one. The second column, ex. 00[0]0, is the 'twos' column. The third column, ex. 0[0]00, is the fours column. The fourth column [0]000 is the 'eights' column. Notice how the power values are, increasing in powers of two. Make more sense now?

So what makes these circuits work? Consider the half-adder. Those inputs a and b represent some arbitrary value coming from the outside. The first portion of the half adder is a `xor` gate. Look in the table for what happens when two true values are applied (1's), the output is 0. Therefore the sum is zero. Now consider the `and` gate, what happens when two true values are applied to the and gate? the output is one. So, we derive the sum from the output of the xor gate (which is 0), and we derive the $C_{out}$ from the `and` gate which is (1) if A and B are both (1).

---

### Edit: More Circuits

[image: Adder1]
[image: Adder2]
[image: Adder3]

I've added these and I've also made YouTube video of them working, just as I promised.

---

---

### Videos:

If I get another request, I'll make another video and upload it, showing the internals of what it REALLY looks like as the circuit is going through its cycles.

Here are some [adders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3_ufbPqleM&feature=youtu.be)

Here is a demonstration of the [gates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSDRY_cEu80&feature=youtu.be)

---

Make more sense now?

Comment: Thanks, but i still dont get the binary addition part... I need a better visual scenario, perhaps a simulation of it actually adding... what are two A and B inputs for? And more helpful would be how exactly the logic gates work. I know how logic gates work in my mind, just not knowing how a inverter works. however... if you have a 1 and 1 in both outputs, what does it add up to? if you have a 1 and then a zero, what is it? and vice versa. You see my confusion now? It seems so abstract an Idea for me!!! :( Minecraft redstone is my only visual representation for now.

Comment: making a youtube video with redstone and a binary adder/half-adder would help if you actually showed the outputs coming into redstone lamps! ;)

Comment: I don't play minecraft, but I can see if I can make the explanation better.

Comment: ok you can try? but a vid would REALLY HELP ME! I'm a visual and reading learner. I try to make an image in my head from reading to remember it. I look at an Image/word and I remember it after seeing it 3 times or looking at it for a couple seconds. but vids I can remember immediately (Dont ask why... I have near-photographic memory).

Comment: Shoot me an email at alexander.alvonellos at gmail.com

Comment: What application are you using to draw the circuits?

Comment: I'm going to have to make a YouTube video and it's going to take me a minute. I'll have to email that video to you tomorrow after I upload it to youtube.

Comment: Digital Works is the software I use. It also does simulation of circuits, and I'm going to use it and CamStudio to upload it to YouTube.

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I'm also going to scan in the entire series of notes I took with my digital logic class with all my drawings and resources and stuff and send those to you also. I'm trying to prepare a whole care package for you as we speak. I can see you're interested in this stuff and I want to help you in any way I can.

Comment: my email is linktheprogrammer@gmail.com... thanks that you will make a video, as this is confusing still. an animated gif could also do... and one thing I have to know... what is a 0 considered on actual hardware? a flow with no electrons? and then a 1 is a flow of electrons? and then for a NOT-gate, when a 0 passes, how does it return a 1 instead on the other end? it needs current!

Comment: and my privelages on stackoverflow and programmer are revoked :( I think the AI is kinda flawed because I have 1 exp on programmer really. I have like one post. I also didnt get really any upvotes much. Now all of a sudden I have legit, useful questions and I can't ask because of this :(

Comment: 0 and 1 don't indicate flow of electrons. They indicate the potential levels. Suppose, $A$ and $B$ are connected to an AND gate. When someone asks what is the output when $A=0$ and $B=1$, what they actually mean is that suppose $A$ is maintained at a low voltage(typically 0V) and $B$ is maintained at a high voltage(typically 5V), then how does the circuit inside the AND gate behave and what will be the output voltage of the AND gate? Electrons always flow through the circuit (provided power is on) and Kirchoff's first law is never violated

Comment: @LinkTheProgrammer I'll see if I can do anything to help you with your stackoverflow account. I'll try to shoot you an email tomorrow about this topic -- but for now, I'm tired.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm not going to get awarded the answer :(

Comment: hi again. sadly, you were helpful but didn't answer me :( thanks though! I saw a video on binary and how transistors work: Logic gates CHECK. That vid also explained how the adders work: Binary addition/subtraction CHECK. EDIT: now what are binary counters!? Every new thing to explain something I already don't know doesn't help much! ;)

Comment: A binary counter is just a binary adder that continually adds one! I used them in this example to speed things up, don't really pay attention to them because without them I'd have to cycle though everything manually. What else do I need to show you to get this marked as an answer?

Comment: well You showed me how binary adders work so... that was the thing I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Well, @LinkTheProgrammer, I'm glad!!!